# A blob moving through a pipe that contracts and deforms

Tags: animation, webgl

I want to have a pipe with elastic walls that one or more blobs can move into which stretch the pipe.

I also want the pipe to be able to contract in diameter and have pressure applied from the outside which push the blobs along.

The blobs should also deform if the right amount of force is applied, and break apart if even more force is applied.

I want this to run inside a browser using WebGL. I am interested in 2D but also 3D.

It should be interactive. The user should control the forces applied to the pipe.

From my research it seems the blobs should probably be soft-bodies maybe using "rigid-body based deformation". Another alternative I considered would be fluid using particles.

What would be best to implement this?

How would the pipe be represented?

Comment: It sounds like you have a viable solution in mind, using soft body deformation. How have you tried putting this idea into practice? Did you get stuck with any specific part we can help you with?

Comment: Just finding which library to use to start. I discovered Box2D + LiquidFun which has an example called "elastic particles" which is pretty much what I want. Matter.js also has a buggy soft body example.

Comment: "Which library to use" is not a class of question we answer here. It sounds like you've found two candidates you can try. Have you tried using either of them and run into a step you need help with?